# Best place to put bug reports?

Tags: documentation

What websites or other resources do users of Blender have available to them to report bugs or problems with the program?

I would like to get this issue cleared in Q&A format so that we can link new users with bug-report-style questions to this post.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**First**, the most [important thing](http://archive.blender.org/development/report-a-bug) to do is:

> ## Make sure it's really a bug
>
> We can only support the Blender binaries as have been distributed on
> blender.org. First thing to test is therefore always if official
> releases have the error. And if there's an error, test it with at
> least one older official release to verify. This can reveal problems
> with your graphics drivers for example, it's not likely that big
> errors are there for many releases!
>
> If the error is in current svn, try a build from someone else
> (http://www.graphicall.org) or official test builds from (http://builder.blender.org) and when possible test it on another system.

The first thing users should do is try to consistently recreate the 'bug'. If you can repeat it, create a **small and simplified** test file (removing anything not needed to reproduce the bug) and submit it with a writeup of said bug.

Reports of "random crashes" or stuff that "breaks at unspecified situations" are unhelpful. Reporting them only creates noise and distraction rather than helping, if a developer can't reliably reproduce it he can't fix it.

If it is a graphical glitch, user interface corruption, viewport artifacts or any other issue related to graphics cards, the second step is **updating your graphics cards to the latest available version**. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date, check the manufacturer site or the official brand site for newer versions. Many purported bugs in Blender are actually issues with the GPU that have recently been worked out in latest versions.

Likewise make sure there are no newly introduced known issues with the lastest drivers. Drivers themselves are also susceptible to bugs and some times newest versions introduce new issues. If you recently upgraded your hardware or installed updartes, rollback to last known good configuration and test if the issue is still there.

## Reporting

The only place to report bugs is the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/). Developers spend considerable time triaging new reports, avoid posting  duplicates. Browse through the already listed bugs in the tracker to **see if someone else has already reported it**, search using different keyword combinations to find similar issues. If nothing comes up then you would want to create an account, sign in and click *Submit New* to file a new bug report. The submission form is very intuitive and lists some guidelines for submitting reports. **A** `.blend` **file must be attached.** Try to make the file as simple as possible (remove anything not strictly necessary to reproduce the issue) and clearly write the steps you took to discover the bug.

You can also quickly reach the bug tracker from inside Blender by going to the *Help > Report a Bug* menu.

[image]

Bugs with user installed, third party or external addons, maintained by independent authors or companies not officially associated with the Blender foundation should be reported to the respective authors, not the official bug tracker.

For very simple problems or things users are not sure about, before filing a report, users can always visit the `#blendercoders` channel on freenode.net via the [webchat](http://webchat.freenode.net) to voice their concerns and or request clarification or tips from the developers.

Additionally, here are some more [bug reporting tips](http://nicholasbishop.net/?p=529) from a developer.

> It may sound annoying to follow all these steps, but remember that if
> you don’t, the developers waste time figuring it all out themselves or
> trying to coax the information out of the user for each bug. Some
> developers like Sergey, Campbell ([ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42)), and Brecht ([brecht](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/242/brecht)) handle a huge number of
> bug reports; you can really help them out by filling good ones.

You can also watch on [YouTube How to Report a Bug in 5 Steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4)

Answer (score 13):

### 1 Introduction

The right place to report bugs is [Blender's bug tracker](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues). Before you start writing your ticket, please read the following post. It will help you write a good bug report that allows developers to identify the source of the problem and thus fix the issue as soon as possible.

---

### 2 Preparation

The first step is to ensure that the issue is actually a bug in Blender and that you can provide enough information for others to
reproduce it on their system.

**2.1 Minimum requirements**

In order to run Blender properly, you have to ensure that your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). The supported graphics
cards are particularly important. If your hardware is not supported, you may experience graphics glitches, crashes or may not be able
to start Blender at all. The developers do not provide support on the bug tracker for hardware that doesn't meet the minimum requirements.

Please note that the [requirements for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware) are higher than the minimum requirements for running Blender. In case you don't see any GPUs listed as render device in the preferences ("No compatible GPUs found for path tracing"), then this is most likely the reason why. It could also happen that your graphics driver is out-dated as explained in the next section.

If you're able to start Blender, you can get all the system information through *Help > Save System Info*.

---

**2.2 Update graphics driver**

Crashes of Blender or even the entire operating system can be caused by bugs in the graphics driver. Updating the graphics driver to the most recent version should minimize the likelihood that this is the cause of your problem. You may have to update the driver for both your integrated GPU and dedicated GPU.

[Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/gpu/index.html) provides additional information for troubleshooting on all supported operating systems.

**2.2.1 Windows**

The most recent driver for [Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en), [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support) and [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/) graphics cards can be downloaded from their respective websites.

**2.2.2 macOS**

On macOS the graphics card driver is tied to the operating system version, therefore it may be necessary to update the OS.

At the time of writing the GPU rendering support for Cycles is limited. GPU rendering with OpenCL is only available in versions prior to 2.80 because Apple has deprecated their OpenCL compiler. GPU rendering with CUDA is only possible in versions before 2.9x because Nvidia discontinued the development of the CUDA Toolkit for macOS. For a more detailed explanation see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/198660/74827). As a consequence you may not find your GPUs listed as supported render device in the user preferences. This is not a bug.

**2.2.3 Linux**

Please note that OpenCL GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards on Linux requires the installation of the AMDGPU-PRO Driver. Consult your distribution's documentation to install and update the driver.

---

**2.3 Reproducible steps and minimal project**

Try to identify and write down a precise list of steps that result in the issue that you're experiencing. Ideally these instructions should allow to reproduce the problem beginning from the default startup file. If the problem only occurs in a specific project, try to create a minimal version of it. Remove anything that's not relevant to the issue.

The instructions should be detailed enough that anyone who is proficient in Blender is able to produce the same result that you're getting. Please use standard nomenclature in your description. Should you be unsure how certain parts of the user interface are called, consult the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html).

---

**2.4.1 Test the latest versions**

The issue may already be fixed in a more recent version of Blender. Test with both the [latest stable release](https://www.blender.org/download/) and the [most recent daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

If you need to test a specific project file, create a backup copy of it. This is meant as a precaution, since files saved in a newer version of Blender may not open in the older versions of Blender that you're usually using. When you're trying to check if the issue still occurs in the most recent version of Blender, use *File > Open* to load the project file. Don't open the project file from your operating system's file browser as this may open a different version of Blender that is associated with the file extension.

In case the issue doesn't occur in the latest stable release, you should continue to use that version. If the issue is fixed in the daily build, you should continue to use your current version and update as soon as a new stable release is published.

**2.4.2 Test previous versions (optional)**

If you are able to, check if you can find the *most recent* [previous releases of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/) that does *not* have the issue. This can help the developers to narrow down when the bug was introduced and what change has caused it. The portable releases (`*.zip` and `*.tar.xz`) don't require any installation, they just have to be extracted and thus allow for easy testing. You should *not* test further back than Blender 2.79b.

---

**2.5 Check if it's a (new) bug**

If you're unsure whether or not the issue is a bug, or if it could be a misunderstanding how Blender works, post a question on one of our [community websites](https://www.blender.org/community/). For example:

- [Blender's chat support channel](https://blender.chat/channel/support)
- [Blender's StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)
- [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/c/support/)

In case your issue requires an enhancement or new feature in Blender, [it's not a bug](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Not_a_bug). Feature requests can be posted on [right-click select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect).

Should you be fairly certain that it's a bug, [verify that it hasn't already been reported](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/). If you find an existing ticket that matches your issue exactly *and* others had trouble reproducing it, please add your step by step instructions in a comment.

---

**2.6 Create a debug log**

Blender can output detailed debug information when one of the [debug CLI flags](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#debug-options) are used. If you're either experiencing a crash or Blender displays an error message, you should create a debug log file that can be attached to your bug report.

Additional log files with different CLI flags may be requested by the developers, but should't be provided up front.

**2.6.1 Windows**

Open Blender's installation directory and double-click on the `blender_debug_log.cmd`. This will start Blender in debug mode and create log files. Try to reproduce the error while Blender is open in debug mode. Close it once the error occured. The Windows Explorer should open automatically and show you two files. Copy them to a location that you know and attach them to your bug report in the following chapter.

In case Blender 2.9x or later crashes, it will create a crash log that contains valuable information about where the error occurred. This file should also be attached to your report. The location is determined by the environment variable `TEMP`. If you haven't modified this environment variable, it will point to `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Temp\` (replace `[your username]` with the actual username on your system). In order to locate the crash log, open the Windows Explorer (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and type `%TEMP%` into the path bar. The name of the crash log will be the same as your project file, but with the file extension `.crash.txt`. If you haven't previously saved the project before, it will be `blender.crash.txt`.

**2.6.1 Linux**

Open Blender and save the system information through *Help > Save System Info*. Open a terminal in Blender's installation directory and start Blender with the `--debug` and `--debug-cycles` flag. Redirect the output for both stdout and stderr to a file. The example command below places the log file in your home directory.

```
./blender --debug --debug-cycles > ~/blender_debug_output.txt 2>&1
```

Attach the system information and log file to your bug report in the following chapter.

In case Blender 2.9x or later crashes, it will also create a crash log that contains a stack trace. The file can be found in the `/tmp` directory. It will be named like your project file, but with the file extension `.crash.txt`. If you haven't previously saved the project before, it will be saved as `blender.crash.txt`. This file should also be attached to your report.

**2.6.2 macOS**

Open Blender and save the system information through *Help > Save System Info*. Open a terminal and start Blender with the `--debug` and `--debug-cycles` flag. Redirect the output for both stdout and stderr to a file. The example command below places the log file in your home directory.

```
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender --debug --debug-cycles > ~/blender_debug_output.txt 2>&1
```

Attach the system information and log file to your bug report in the following chapter.

In case Blender crashes the macOS Crash Reporter will open and show you a detailed report with a stack trace. You should copy the text, save it in a text file and also attach it to your report.

---

### 3 Create the report

Create an account on [developer.blender.org](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues).

There are two different templates for reporting bugs, one for add-ons and one for Blender itself.

**If you want to report a bug in an add-on:**

1. Open Blender.
2. Open the preferences and navigate to the add-ons (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).
3. Find the add-on you would like to report a bug for.
4. Check that it's an official add-on that is shipped with Blender. If it isn't, contact the developer directly.
   The bug tracker is only for add-ons that are distributed with Blender.
5. Open the details section of the add-on and click *Report a Bug*.

**If you want to report a bug in Blender:**

1. Open Blender.
2. Use *Help > Report a Bug*.
3. Add which versions of Blender do not work.
4. Add which version of Blender works.

**If you cannot open Blender and want to report a bug:**

1. Use the [bug report template](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/new/choose).
2. Add your operating system and graphics card information.
3. Add which versions of Blender do not work.
4. Add which version of Blender works.

Once you've logged in you should see the submission template. Anything in square brackets should be replaced
with the information about your problem. Should you have trouble writing in English, then please write the report in your native language and include a machine translated text alongside.

1. Give your ticket a descriptive title. It should ideally explain what's broken and where.
2. Add a short description of your problem to *"Short description of the error"*. You may include a screenshot
   if the problem is hard to describe.
3. Add the detailed steps to reproduce the issue from section *"2.3 Reproducible steps and minimal project"* to
   *"Exact steps for others to reproduce the error"*.
4. Attach your system information file, debug log and crash log to the bug report by pressing the upload button or dragging and dropping the file into the browser window.
5. Attach your .blend project file (only if the bug can't be reproduced with the default startup file).
6. Click "Create New Task" to create the bug report.

**3.1 Example of a good bug report**

Title: Crash using color drag and drop in the image editor

```
**System Information**
Operating system: Windows-10-10.0.18362 64 Bits
Graphics card: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 NVIDIA Corporation 4.5.0 NVIDIA 436.30

**Blender Version**
Broken: 
 - version: 2.82 (sub 7), branch: master, commit date: 2020-03-12 05:06, hash: `rB375c7dc4caf4`
 - version: 2.83 (sub 12), branch: master, commit date: 2020-04-06 15:48, hash: `rB71a52bbe2a2e`
Worked: 2.80

**Short description of error**
Blender crashes when dragging and dropping a color onto the texture in the image editor.

**Exact steps for others to reproduce the error**
 1. Open the Texture Paint workspace.
 2. Create a new texture in the image editor.
 3. Put the mouse cursor over the current color in the header and drag it onto the texture.
```

---

### 4 Triage and bug fix

Once your bug report is submitted, volunteers and developers will try to reproduce the issue. They may have additional questions, so check once in a while if somebody has left a comment on your ticket. If the status of your ticket is "Needs information from user" and you do not reply within a week, the ticket will be closed.

- **Do not** assign the task to anyone (unless they've told you to).
- **Do not** change the status.
- **Do not** change the priority.
- **Do not** change the edit policy.
- **Do not** edit parent or subtasks.

The ticket will then go through the ["Life of a Bug"](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/A_Bugs_Life). Once the bug is confirmed the developers will try to fix this as soon as possible. Please be aware that the developers get many bug reports and the more serious ones are being prioritized. It may take a while until the issue is fixed.

*Please be kind*, many of the people helping on the bug tracker are volunteers and our developers are working as hard as they can.